# How to remove all first characters if all are digits in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel file like this

```
983 David
75Harshan
0 vivek
```

I want to remove 983 from excel cell 1, remove 75 from second cell, remove 0 from third cell. How this possible? ie. I want to remove all the prefixing digits from an excel cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any version of Excel that supports VBA, consider the following User Defined Function:

Option Explicit

```
Public Function NoDig(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long, CH As String
    NoDig = s
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Left(NoDig, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
            NoDig = Mid(NoDig, 2, 9999)
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: Nice. The same logic as my lambda, in fact, but most people can't use lambda yet so this is more useful.

Answer (score 2):

This formula will retain all of the string in A1 except any leading numeric characters. Copy down as required.

```
=MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))),0),LEN(A1))
```

The formula works as is on Excel 365. For earlier versions of Excel you may have to enter it as an array formula (confirm with Ctl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: Beat me to it. So +1.  But I'd suggest the non-volatile `ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))` in place of the volatile `INDIRECT` to generate the array.  (or `SEQUENCE` if using 365).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Indeed, volatility could be an issue if the formula is intended to remain in the workbook and the number of rows is large (several thousands). So, it's definitely an alternative and, potentially, a better one.

Comment: I am only saying this because you have posted a better solution, but it does error out if you have a string like "a" or "123". Probably these won't occur in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array formula like

```
=IF(A2="","",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-MAX(IF(((CODE(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1))<48)+(CODE(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1))>57)),0,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2))))))
```

or (more fun) a Lambda RemoveDigits(s) if you have it

```
=LAMBDA(s,IF(s="","",IF(OR(CODE(LEFT(s))<48,CODE(LEFT(s))>57),s,RemoveDigits(RIGHT(s,LEN(s)-1)))))
```

Note that these give different results in the last example:

[image]

I've replaced the first formula with something more or less equivalent to the lambda.

Comment: I think Lambda is a relatively new function, when does it available to Excel?

Comment: This code =RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2),0))) removes only first 0 from my cell

Comment: Yes, you have to have Excel 365 and sign up for the insider program https://insider.office.com/en-gb/join/windows (depending on platform) at time of writing.

Comment: Yes you're right @Nidhi unfortunately, it only works if the digits are all different! So Variatus has the correct formula. I will see if I can think of a way to find the last digit when there is a repeated digit.

Comment: I've replaced the first formula with something more or less equivalent to the lambda.

Comment: @TomSharpe I am using paid version of Excel. But I don't have 365 yet

Comment: You can use ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))) instead of Sequence(len(A1)), or ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))) as suggested by @Ron Rosenfeld in earlier version of Excel. But there is no reason not to simply use Variatus's formula.

Answer (score -2):

Use text to columns, sort all data with space. And then use space as delimiters